# C# and msaccess, save Datagrid

Tags: c#, database, datagrid, ms-access-2007

I writing an adressbook (with a datagrid view in it. When changing the cells in the datagrid there is a possibility to save 
the changes. Therefore I have the following code:

```
private void btnSaveGrid_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) 
{
    try 
    {
        OleDbConnection cn = new OleDbConnection();
                OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand();
                cn.ConnectionString = @"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=C:\myFolder\myDatabase.accdb;Persist Security Info=False;";
                cn.Open();

                cmd.Connection = cn;
                cmd.CommandText = " SELECT * FROM myTable ";

                OleDbDataAdapter dAdapter = new OleDbDataAdapter(cmd.CommandText, cn);
                OleDbCommandBuilder builder = new OleDbCommandBuilder(dAdapter);

                dAdapter.Update(dTable); 
                cn.Close();
                MessageBox.Show("Information update", "Update", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);

    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
    }

}
```

the dTable is (DataTable dTable = new DataTable(); is writen before the InitializeComponent.

Now the problem is that when the cells are changed in the datagrid view but the databases isn't update with the new information!
The messagebox didn't give an Error but the information Update.

What Iam doing wrong??

Thanks in advance

Comment: You need to create and fill the data adapter one time, not on every button click. See [this](http://contrivedexample.com/2015/03/14/a-basic-example-of-crud-with-datagridview-in-vb-net/) VB.net sample.

Answer (score 0):

Refer to this documentation :
[Updating data sources with DataAdapter](https://msdn.microsoft.com/tr-tr/library/33y2221y(v=vs.110).aspx)

You first need to write your own update logic in order to make it work.

And of course as @Crowcoder mentioned you also need to bind data to the DataTable with fill command before doing any updates...